# Table Row Traversing with JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table formatted like that following:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="node">
            <td onclick='toggleDesc(this.parentNode);'>blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subnode">
            <td>sblah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subnode">
            <td>sblah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subnode">
            <td>sblah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="node">
            <td onclick='toggleDesc(this.parentNode);'>blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subnode">
            <td>sblah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subnode">
            <td>sblah</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have a function that toggles the display of the `.subnode` classes based on the TD of the `.node` above it. The function looks like this:

```
function toggleDesc(item) {
    var descRow = item.nextElementSibling;
    $(descRow).toggleClass("descDisplay");
}
```

However, the function above only toggles the display of the first `.subnode` it encounters. Does anyone know how to `.toggleClass` for each `.subnode` after `.node` until the next `.node` is hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nextUntil()`:

```
$(item).nextUntil('tr.node').toggleClass("descDisplay");
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

Comment: Perfect, this will do. Didn't know of `.nextUntil` method. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using something like `$(item).nextUntil(".node, .subnode").toggleClass("descDisplay")`.

Comment: `.nextUntil('tr.node')` will do in this case.